Ubuntu is working on my new Lenovo system but the sound still doesn't work. Why?
i have ubunto on my lenovo ideapad slim3 ,
the audio card not installed and i cant install it . . .
Does anyone have this problem?
i tried to install alsa driver and alsa lib and alsa utils but it's not working . . .
is there anyone to had the same problem

This question would be proper on AskUbuntu
